# Is there any Linq like feature in any languages prior to .NET?

Tags: .net, linq

I was wondering, if there are examples of Linq like features in other languages and programming platforms prior to .NET or this was the invention of Microsoft.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Many of the ideas behind LINQ are [borrowed from functional programming languages](http://blogs.msdn.com/charlie/archive/2007/01/26/anders-hejlsberg-on-linq-and-functional-programming.aspx), although Microsoft is the first that I'm aware of that has packaged up these ideas into an in-language query language that resembles SQL, and in fact can be translated to SQL at runtime.

The underlying concepts, though, are nearly as old as computers, in many cases.

Answer (score 1):

See [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linq)

> While LINQ is primarily implemented as
>   a library for .NET Framework 3.5, it
>   also defines a set of language
>   extensions that can be optionally
>   implemented by languages to make
>   queries a first class language
>   construct and provide syntactic sugar
>   for writing queries. These language
>   extensions have initially been
>   implemented in C# 3.0, VB 9.0 and
>   Oxygene, with other languages like F#
>   and Nemerle having announced
>   preliminary support.